# Is there a recent version of Visual Studio Team Edition for Database Professionals?

Tags: visual-studio, database-versioning

I was just looking into some articles about version control for databases and came across a blog by Jeff Atwood where he recommends Visual Studio Team Edition for Database Professionals.  He provided a link to a trial, but the only problem is that that trial is from 2005.

Is this product a separate version of Visual Studio altogether, or is it some sort of add-in?  And in either case, is there a recent version of it?  I don't see anything for 2012 when I google it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2012, [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh297027) replaced and provided conversion capability for existing Visual Studio database projects.

Previously these were called Database Projects in Visual Studio since 2010 (and before that, GDR in 2008)

> If you already have the Professional, Ultimate, or Premium Edition of
>   Visual Studio 2012 and didn't opt out of installing SQL Server Data
>   Tools during setup, then your machine has an existing installation of
>   SSDT.

- [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/tools)

Comment: Awesome!  I'm going to be upgrading to 2012 very soon so that's good to know.